# JSON Parsing filter comma separated records

Tags: java, android, json

First JSON:

```
{
    "datas":[
        {
            "id":"1",
            "name":"Name 1",
            "users":"1,3"
        },
        {
            "id":"2",
            "name":"Name 2",
            "users":"2,5"
        }
    ]
}
```

Second JSON:

```
{
    "users":[
        {
            "id":"1",
            "name":"User 1"
        },
        {
            "id":"2"
            "name":"User 2"
        }
    ......
    ]
}
```

but I am always getting list of all users, no matter where i have tapped (Name 1 or Name 2)

this is what i am using to get filtered users only based on id:

```java
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
    try {
        String[] strMultiUsers = strEventUsers.split(",");
        List<String> listMultiUsers = Arrays.asList(strMultiUsers);           

        HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if (status == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


            JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
            JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("users");

            for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                UsersList oldEventsList = new UsersList();

                oldEventsList.setId(object.getString("id"));                        
                oldEventsList.setName(object.getString("name"));

                if(listMultiUsers.contains(""))
                {

                }

                oldEventsArrayList.add(oldEventsList);
            }
            return true;
        }
```

I want whenever user does tap on Name 2, i have to show only two users (user with id - 2 and 5) but still i am getting all users (1 to 5)

Comment: Use JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("datas"); datas is your JSONarray.

Comment: If you have delimited values in JSON, you're doing something wrong.  Use an array or an object (in this case array).

Comment: @AvishekDas hey i have written i am list of all users, i have not mentioned anywhere that i am not getting users list.. check both the jsons above, because first json connects to second JSON

Comment: i found the solution and placed for other developers, and will accept my answer in next 2 days :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, and placing for other developers:

```
String strUsers = object.getString("id").toString();
Log.d("users", strUsers);

usersList.setName(object.getString("name"));

if(listMultiUsers.contains(strUsers))
 {
     usersListArrayList.add(usersList);
 }
```